# React updating shopping cart when item selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and I am working on a flight project. 
I am attempting to update a shopping cart when items are selected. I am aware the structure of the code might not be the best way, but this is what I have so far.

```
Export class DestinationPrices extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            flightData: [],
            checked:false,
            data:'',
            cart:[]
        };

        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.handleAddToCart = this.handleAddToCart.bind(this);

    }
```

```
 NavCart() {

        return (

            <div className="Nav" >
                <Card body >

          <CardTitle ><h3><b>Flights Selected : </b></h3></CardTitle>
    <CardText >
<span className="fa fa-cart-plus fa-2x"> {this.props.cart.length}</span> 
    </CardText>


                </Card>
            </div>
            )
    }
```

That is the cart itself which should update number of items when selected.
Below is the Select method which you can select the different cards.

```
Select(FD) {

 this.state={route:''};

       return (
           <div>
               {FD.FlightID}
            <label>

                <Checkbox id={FD.FlightID}
                          name={FD.FlightID}
                          checked={this.setState.route}

                 onChange={(()=> this.handleCheckboxChange(FD.FlightID))}
               handleClick={()=>{this.handleClick(FD.FlightID)}}

                />
                <span>Select</span>
            </label>
           </div>


        )
    }
```

These are the functions I have to handle the changes

```
 handleCheckboxChange =(id) =>{
        var data;
        const selected = (e => e.FlightID = id);
        this.handleAddToCart(id);
    };

    handleAddToCart(flight) {
        const cartItem = this.state.cart.find(x => x.id === flight.id);
        this.setState({cart: [...this.state.cart, flight]})
    }

    handleClick(flight) {
        this.handleAddToCart(flight)
    }
```

If anyone is able to help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the error is on that line? The `const selected = (e => e.FlightID = id);` looks like it might cause a problem, I think you'd want `===` there... though I can't see at the moment where `selected` is being used. Are you able to provide the error message?

Comment: I updated it to === there but still throwing same error , just realized it's an undefined error so I probably have something going wrong before then

Comment: ah ok - are you able to provide any more detail on the error message?

Comment: Error is : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined`,  I called the  `this.handleAddToCart(id)` inside the `handleCheckboxChange` function , maybe that is what is causing the error? Probably not how it is supposed to be done. I had it in the `handleClick()` function but i wasn't able to get it to work.

Comment: It should be possible to call these functions as you have it, but I'm not sure whether or not you need to bind `this` for `handleCheckboxChange`. It might be worth trying that first as it seems like that _may_ solve the problem

Comment: @OliverRadini ok perfect, thanks very much for your help, I'll give that a try!

Comment: hopefully that works. `this` is fairly confusing and it _can_ be easier to avoid it altogether using things like [functional components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) and [state hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)